# sending HUGE JSON data to the server throw postforobject method

Tags: java, android, json, spring, post

I keep receiving a 400 BAD request when sending a POST request using RestTemplate.
i am sending a list of object and for that i've created a class AllCars witch hase as an field listof Cars this my class:

```
public class AllCars {

    private List<Cars> listcars;

    public AllCars() {
    }

    public AllCars(List<Cars> listcars) {
        this.listcars = listcars;
    }

    public List<Cars> getListcars() {
        return listcars;
    }

    public void setListcars(List<Cars> listcars) {
        this.listcars = listcars;
    }
}
```

Cars class

```
public class Cars {


    private Long id;
    private long speed;
    private String color;

    public Cars() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    public long getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(long speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

this is my client side code:

```
private class SendData extends AsyncTask<AllCars, Object, AllCars> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Downloading", "Downloading..Please Wait", true);

    }

    @Override
    protected AllCars doInBackground(AllCars... params) {
        try {

        // urls
            final String urlCars = "http://myurl/addCars";
             publishProgress(0);

             RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            // Add the Jackson and String message converters
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            AllCars result = restTemplate.postForObject(urlAllCars, params[0], AllCars.class);

              return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("mainactivity", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AllCars ob) {


            if(ob instanceof  AllCars)
        Log.d("AllCars", "success " );

        else
            Log.d("No Result ", "");




        progressDialog.cancel();
    }

}
```

and this is my server side code:

```
@Requesrmaping (vlaue = "/addCars", method=RequestMethod.POST)

    public ResponseEntity<AllCars>addCars(@RequestBody AllCars allcars){
    List<Cars> listcar= allcars.getListcars();
    return new ResponsEntity<AllCars>(allcars,HttpStatus.ok)
}
```

this code works when the listcare has one object but when it have more than one object it doesn't work could any body help me

Comment: can you share the Cars class also and also share the request you are trying to POST, and what is the params[0]?

Comment: thanks for your replay i've update my code wiht class Cars and server side code and client side code i didn't figure out the problem

Comment: also please add `params[0]` value you are passing, can you debug and check

Comment: params[0] is object of class AllCars